# Java-Collection: What collection to use is this very specific case?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have the following scenario and am looking for the "best" implementation:

1. I want to store items in a `java.util.Collection` to implement an interface
2. All items are guaranteed to have a unique `hashCode`
3. I know the max number `n` of items to be stored (max `capacity` is known on initialization)
4. The `hashCode` is between `0` to `n`
5. Order is not important, duplicates are not wanted (`Set`-properties are desired)
6. Items can be added, but will never be removed
7. Performance of `contains` is very important (desired: `O(1)`, at least `O(log_n)`)

My first thought was to use a `new HashSet<item>(n+1, 1.0)`, but after some reading I found that it applies an internal hash function to the `hashCode` of the item, so hash collisions will still occur, even though the `hashCodes` are unique and `hachCode <= n`.

My second thought was to use a native array (`new item[n]`) and use the `hashCode` as index. This seems to be the implementation with the best performance, but my interface expects a `java.util.Collection` and the collection will be used with `contains` and `add`, which is not compatible with the benefits of this second approach.

Am I missing something, or do I have to accept the overhead and collisions of the `HashSet` to get the best performance?

Comment: Use a hashset and don't worry about performance unless you actually observe performance problems.

Comment: can't you just define your own `hashCode()` method, if you are worried about hash collisions? And, given that hash collisions are rare - why would it matter even?

Comment: I would simply go for HashSet. It fulfills all the requirements you have specified. No duplicate, O(1) retrieval. Also, since it is a standard java class, you manipulations for data to different structure/ordering etc will be easier to do than if you provide your own custom implementation.

Comment: if you know in advance what elements will be in the collection, you can try to come up with a hashCode function that gives a unique result for each of these elements; otherwise, collisions are just a fact of life.

Comment: @vikingsteve @Maurice See point 2. of my question. The `hashCode()` method of my `item` class is not the problem, but internally `HashSet` uses another hashing algorithm to compute the bucket based on the `hashCode` of the item. This ensures that even objects with poorly implemented `hashCode`s can be stored efficiently. It basically leads to few collisions, but almost never none.

Comment: What is the big issue with collisions, given they are infrequent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `HashSet` will still give you good performance, but given the specific requirements you describe (and assuming `n` it not too large), you can create you own "ArraySet" implementation of the `Set` interface:

- It will have a backing array of length `n+1` to store the data.
- `contains` will use the `hashCode` of an element to find if the index matching that `hashCode()` has a non null value.
- `add` will use the `hashsCode` of the added element to find the index of the array to which you should add the element.
- Any other required methods will be implemented similarly.

This solution may be slightly more efficient than `HashSet`, since it contains less overhead. It will, however, be expansive in terms of memory usage if `n` is large.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirement, I suggest you to use HashSet. It will perform better.  As you mentioned that the maximum number of elements and the maximum capacity of Set, both are of same size. Further each element have an unique hashcode. In that case, there is rare change of hash key collision. So dont worry about the contains function. With the mentioned dataset the **contains** will perform in O(1). Similarly the **add** will also perform in constant order. i.e. O(1).